# Subset by multiple conditions

Tags: r, subset

Maybe it's something basic, but I couldn't find the answer.
I have

```
Id Year V1  
 1 2009 33   
 1 2010 67  
 1 2011 38  
 2 2009 45  
 3 2009 65  
 3 2010 74  
 4 2009 47  
 4 2010 51  
 4 2011 14
```

I need to select only the rows that have the same Id but it´s in the three years 2009, 2010 and 2011.

```
Id Year V1  
 1 2009 33  
 1 2010 67  
 1 2011 38  
 4 2009 47  
 4 2010 51  
 4 2011 14
```

I try

```
d1_3 <- subset(d1, Year==2009 |Year==2010 |Year==2011 )
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone provide some suggestions that how I can do this in R?

Comment: +1 for posting a minimal example, the expected output and the code you have tried, in your first post on SO!

Comment: I suppose you meant 'Year' where you have written 'ANNO'?

Comment: That's right! it's because the original database is from Spain, so we said "año" = ANNO, for don't work in R with "ñ", but the meaning is year. Thanks again.That right! it's because the original database is from Spain, so we said "año" = ANNO, for don't work in R with "ñ", but the meaning is year. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `ave` could be useful here. I call your original data frame 'df'. For each Id, check if 2009-2011 is present in Year (`2009:2011 %in% x`). This gives a logical vector, which can be `sum`med. Test if the sum equals 3 (if all Years are present, the sum is 3), which results in a new logical vector, which is used to subset rows of the data frame.

```
df[ave(df$Year, df$Id, FUN = function(x) sum(2009:2011 %in% x) == 3, ]
#   Id Year V1
# 1  1 2009 33
# 2  1 2010 67
# 3  1 2011 38
# 7  4 2009 47
# 8  4 2010 51
# 9  4 2011 14
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! It seems work well. Select the observantions that have the years.

Comment: @Tappin73, please note that I changed `x %in% 2009:2011` to `2009:2011 %in% x`. Compare e.g. `c(2009, 2009, 2009) %in% 2009:2011` and `2009:2011 %in% c(2009, 2009, 2009)`

Comment: @Henrik : your change shouldn't make any difference.. because you will still get exactly 3 as sum in either case.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil, Thanks for your comment! `sum(c(2009, 2009, 2009) %in% 2009:2011)` is 3, despite not all years are represented. That's why I swapped them.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job :)

```
library(plyr)
ds<-ddply(ds,.(Id),mutate,Nobs=length(Year))
ds[ds$Nobs == 3 & ds$Year %in% 2009:2011,]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but doesn´t solve the issue. It´s continue  selecting some observations that only have one or two years. I would select all the observations that have all years in the survey (2009, 2010 and 2011)

Comment: Sorry, after posting anwser I found mistake. I posted working anwser with plyr package. But if you would like to use standard R function, please see @Henrik anwser.

Comment: This will fail to give if an ID occurs for a year other than and alongwith 2009, 2010, 2011

Comment: But the question is concerning years from 2009 to 2011, so I think that in this case it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of using `ave`

```
DF
##   Id Year V1
## 1  1 2009 33
## 2  1 2010 67
## 3  1 2011 38
## 4  2 2009 45
## 5  3 2009 65
## 6  3 2010 74
## 7  4 2009 47
## 8  4 2010 51
## 9  4 2011 14


DF[ave(DF$Year, DF$Id, FUN = function(x) all(2009:2011 %in% x)) == 1, ]
##   Id Year V1
## 1  1 2009 33
## 2  1 2010 67
## 3  1 2011 38
## 7  4 2009 47
## 8  4 2010 51
## 9  4 2011 14
```

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach using `ave` is reasonable. But there are lots of ways to solve this problem. I show a few other ways using base R. Then in the last 2 examples I'll introduce the package `data.table`.

Again, just throwing this out there to provide some options to use different aspects of the language.

```
d1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4), Year=c(2009,2010,2011, 2009,2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011), V1=c(33, 67, 38, 45, 65, 74, 47, 51, 14))


# long way
use_years <- as.character(2009:2011)
cnts <- table(d1[,c("ID","Year")])[,use_years]
use_id <- rownames(cnts)[rowSums(cnts)==length(use_years)]
d1[d1[,"ID"]%in%use_id,]
# 1  1 2009 33
# 2  1 2010 67
# 3  1 2011 38
# 7  4 2009 47
# 8  4 2010 51
# 9  4 2011 14

# another longish way
ind1 <- d1[,"Year"]%in%2009:2011
d1_ind <- d1[ind1,"ID"]
ind2 <- d1_ind %in% unique(d1_ind)[tabulate(d1_ind)==3]
d1[ind1,][ind2,]
#   ID Year V1
# 1  1 2009 33
# 2  1 2010 67
# 3  1 2011 38
# 7  4 2009 47
# 8  4 2010 51
# 9  4 2011 14
```

OK, let's try out a couple methods using data.table. One of my favorite packages of all time. Can be a little tricky at first though, so make sure your boots are on tight (Oh, yeah, it's fast!) :)

```
# medium way
library(data.table)
d2 <- as.data.table(d1)

d2[ID%in%d2[Year%in%2009:2011, list(logic=nrow(.SD)==3),by="ID"][(logic),ID]]
#    ID Year V1
# 1:  1 2009 33
# 2:  1 2010 67
# 3:  1 2011 38
# 4:  4 2009 47
# 5:  4 2010 51
# 6:  4 2011 14


# short way
d2[Year%in%2009:2011][ID%in%unique(ID)[table(ID)==3]]
#    ID Year V1
# 1:  1 2009 33
# 2:  1 2010 67
# 3:  1 2011 38
# 4:  4 2009 47
# 5:  4 2010 51
# 6:  4 2011 14
```