# subsetting removing too many rows

Tags: r, subset

Given the data below:

```
# Import mock data
Biomass <- c(20, 10, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 22, 13, 13, 15, 18, 2, 5, 7, 10)
Season <- c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall")
Year <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
ReefSpecies <- c("Admiral Ma", "Jaap Mf", "Grecian Ma", "Alligator Mr", "Jaap Mf", "Grecian Ma", "Alligator Mr", "Admiral Ma", "Grecian Ma", "Alligator Mr", "Admiral Ma", "Jaap Mf", "Alligator Mr", "Admiral Ma", "Jaap Mf","Grecian Ma")
Seasonal <- data.frame(Biomass, Season, Year, ReefSpecies)
Seasonal$Times <- paste(Seasonal$Year, Seasonal$Season, sep=" ")
Seasonal$Time <- factor(Seasonal$Times, levels=unique(Seasonal$Times))


# Plot figure
ggplot(data = Seasonal, aes(Time,  Biomass, color=ReefSpecies)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(aes(group=ReefSpecies), method="lm") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270)) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(colour="black", size=1, fill=NA), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
theme(legend.position = "top") +
xlab("Year") +
ylab(bquote("Ash-free Biomass (mg/cm"^"2"*")"))
```

I would like to make a 3 figures which add each species separately.
For example we have three species over four reefs (Admiral Ma and Grecian Ma - 1 species and 2 reefs, Jaap Mf - 1 species and 1 reef, and Alligator Mr - 1 species and 1 reef).
What I would like to is add the **Reef** Ma to the plot first - this would be the first figure.

Next I would like to add another species (say) **Reef** Mf which includes the previous figure - this would be the second plot.

Since the last plot includes all the data, I know how to do that - and just need help with the first two figures.

Attached below is an image of what I have been able to achieve - you will see that using this method not all data points are included (compare to other image of all data in one figure) - code is attached for both figures as well.

**NOTE**: The above data is a small subset of what is plotted below

[image: Subsetted - not all data included]

```
#Subsetted dataset with missing points
ggplot(subset(Seasonal, ReefSpecies == c("Grecian O. faveolata", "Jaap O. faveolata", "Alligator O. faveolata", "Admiral O. faveolata")), 
   aes(Time, Biomass, color = ReefSpecies)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=ReefSpecies), method="lm") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(colour="black", size=1, fill=NA), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab(bquote("Ash-free Biomass (mg/cm"^"2"*")"))
```

This is an example of what I want for the first figure - it includes all of the same species but from all my study locations as well.

Additionally, I receive this warning message - I think it means it is trying to plot an equal number of points for the subset but R warnings can almost be a foreign language to me.

```
Warning message:
In ReefSpecies == c("Grecian O. faveolata", "Jaap O. faveolata",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

[image: Subsetted data with 2 species]

```
ggplot(subset(Seasonal, ReefSpecies == c("Grecian O. faveolata", "Jaap O. faveolata", "Alligator O. faveolata", "Admiral O. faveolata", "Grecian O. annularis", "Jaap O. annularis", "Alligator O. annularis", "Admiral O. annularis")), 
   aes(Time, Biomass, color = ReefSpecies)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=ReefSpecies), method="lm") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(colour="black", size=1, fill=NA), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab(bquote("Ash-free Biomass (mg/cm"^"2"*")"))
```

This is an example of what I want for the first figure - it includes all of the same species but from all my study locations as well.

The same warning message comes up with this plot as well

[image: Whole data set]

**NOTE**: The red line in the subset figure corresponds to the gold line in the whole data figure

The blue line in the subset figure corresponds to the blue line in the whole data figure

The green line in the subset figure corresponds to the green line in the whole data figure

The purple line in the subset figure corresponds to the purple line in the whole data figure

```
# Whole Dataset
ggplot(data = Seasonal, aes(Time,  Biomass, color=ReefSpecies)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(aes(group=ReefSpecies), method="lm") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270)) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(colour="black", size=1, fill=NA), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
theme(legend.position = "top") +
xlab("Year") +
ylab(bquote("Ash-free Biomass (mg/cm"^"2"*")"))
```

As you can see from these two figures - ggplot seems to removing multiple points in the figure when plotting the subset.

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you need anything more from me, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==` in your `subset` condition to check if `ReefSpecies` matches any of the names specified.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I tried that but it says function not found and I get this error     `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "%n%"`

Comment: @MikkoMarttila  Ignore that last comment - this did work!  Thank you!  I needed to try `%in%` not `%n%`

Comment: As a bit of advice for the future - work on narrowing down a problem before tackling it. This isn't a `ggplot` question, or  a plotting question at all. It's a question of how to subset data. If you see a plot that looks wrong, the first thing you should do is check it the data frame you give to the plot is correct. In this case, it's not, and you've narrowed your problem down to a single line of code.

Comment: Then maybe you'd be tempted to take that line apart and run something like `subset(Seasonal, ReefSpecies == c("Grecian O. faveolata", "Jaap O. faveolata")` as a minimal test. When that doesn't work maybe you'd search a bit and find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22475189/903061) or one of many other similar questions.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you for the advice.  I actually did try a minimal test using `subset(Seasonal, ReefSpecies == c("Grecian O. faveolata")` which did produce the correct plot.  But then I couldn't figure out how to add additional `ReefSpecies` combinations.  I will save that source for next time.  I am curious though, since I have always used `==` for subsetting what is the difference between `==` and `%in%`?  They seem to perform almost the same function.  Cheers.

Comment: See [difference between `%in%` VS `==`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15358006/903061). They are quite different. The way to make your subset work with `==` would be `subset(Seasonal, ReefSpecies == "Gregcian O. faveolata" | ReefSpecies = "Jaap O. faveolata" | ReefSpecies == ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare vectors of different length, the shorter vector is recycled to match the length of the longer vector, and then element-wise comparisons are made. Here's a small example:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 2)
y <- c(1, 0)

# compare x with a shorter vector y
x == y
#   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# the previous is actually the same as
x == c(y, y, y[1])
x == c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
#   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# to check for each element of x if it matches any element in y
x %in% y
#   [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The vector of names you wanted to subset by was recycled to the length of your data, and then each record was checked against the corresponding element on the recycled vector of names. Only the observations where the value of `ReefSpecies` happened to correspond with the value in the recycled vector of names were included in the subsetted data.